# Raspberry Pi 2 model B - Mono C# PIN numbering

Tags: c#, .net, gpio, raspberry-pi2

I have Raspberry Pi 2 model B. I use https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net for write apps in C#. I have problem with PIN numbering.

I tried everything, but it does not work.

**Can anybody explain me where I can get PIN number?**

For example: When I have anything on PIN GPIO17 (http://elinux.org/File:Pi-GPIO-header.png on this table), how can I locate it from C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project description suggests

> using Mike McCauley's BCM2835 library which is available here.

Its [documentation](http://www.open.com.au/mikem/bcm2835/index.html) then states

> **Pin Numbering**
>
> The GPIO pin numbering as used by RPi is different to and inconsistent with the underlying BCM 2835 chip pin numbering. http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs
>
> ...
>
> The functions in this library are designed to be passed the BCM 2835 GPIO pin number and not the RPi pin number. There are symbolic definitions for each of the available pins that you should use for convenience. See [RPiGPIOPin](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__constants.html#ga63c029bd6500167152db4e57736d0939).

Luckily these different numbering schemes are resolved by the [GPIOPins enum](https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net/blob/master/RaspberryPiDotNet/GPIOPins.cs) both defined in terms of the BCM GPIO pin numbers (first example) and the GPIO pins on connector P1 (second example):

```
V2_GPIO_00 = 0,
V2_Pin_P1_03 = 2,
```

To pick a pin on the connector use the `_Pin_P1_nn` notation. Just mind the different definitions for the different types and revisions of the Pi.